# Toggle Street View

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

How can I toggle Streetview on an specific map canvas by clicking a button (API v3) ?

```
function ToggleStreetView(map)
{
  //Assume map contains the google.maps.Map object

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the function that I wrote for a maps app that I wrote a while ago:

```
// Toggles between map and panorama view
function togglePanorama(){
    if(isPanorama){
        map.streetView.setVisible(false);
        $('#message').empty().append('Click here to take a tour of our office.');
        isPanorama = 0;
    } else{
        map.streetView.setVisible(true);
        $('#message').empty().append('Back to the map.');
        isPanorama = 1;
    }
}
```

Though I was using it with a custom panorama it will work just fine with the default Street View.

Answer (score 1):

Get the 'streetview' of your map then setVisible to 'false' and your streetview should no longer be visible.

```
// map would be map instance
map.getStreetView().setVisible(false);
```

Answer (score -1):

I assume you are using Javascript version 3 API from google maps
here is a sample code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function initialize() {
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644);
    var myOptions = {
      zoom: 8,
      center: latlng,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
        myOptions);
  }

</script>
```

if you lool carefully you can see line of code

```
mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
```

you can declare our map variable and than iinside your function change its MapTypeId

Comment: That toggles the type of map. I want to be able to switch from map view to street level view (StreetView).